# Are there any speakers that use the Classical Latin pronunciation for Romance languages in informal purposes?

Tags: pronunciation

From what I researched, in Classical Latin, there was a shift of pronounciation, called palatalization which happened during the fall of Rome. This led to the creation of Ecclesiastical Latin which evolved into Romance languages like Italian with the same process of palatalization. However, are there any speakers who use the Classical Latin pronunciation in any informal purposes as a general question?

Comment: You mean for pronouncing modern Romance languages, not for Latin? No, those are different languages that work differently.

Comment: The Romance languages do not descend from Ecclesiastical Latin.

Comment: Note: I just edited my question

Comment: I just undid your edit. Please don't change your question entirely. A moving target is frustrating to the volunteers helping you and invalidates existing answers. Feel free to improve a question through editing, but don't change it. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Given the edits and the confusion in the comments, I'm closing this for now, especially since you've asked another question along these same lines in its wake. If you could clarify a bit more what exactly you're wanting to know, we can open it back up.

Answer (score 4):

You've misunderstood the history of the Romance languages.

Vulgar Latin—that is, the living language actually spoken by many of the subjects of the Roman Empire—underwent a series of sound changes; the earliest of these happened everywhere (the change of unstressed front vowels /i e/ followed by another vowel to /j/ and the subsequent palatalisation of /kj tj/ among them), but as mobility and contact inside the territory of the Empire decreased, later changes were confined to specific geographical regions, leading to the break-up of Latin into the various Romance languages.

*Separate from that*, Latin continued to be used in certain administrative, legal, religious, and other contexts. This Latin—or actually *these Latins*, as there were several—was not a living language (nobody spoke it natively), and deliberately changed much less, especially in its written form. The pronunciation inevitably did drift a bit over time under the influence of local vernaculars, though.
Ecclesiastical Latin is specifically the Latin used by the Catholic Church, with its current pronunciation influenced mainly by Italian. It is not *really* a living language, and it is not the ancestor of any living language.

That said, you're effectively asking if Latin has managed to survive entirely unchanged for two thousand years anywhere. There isn't a single language in the history of mankind that has ever managed to do that.

Answer (score 2):

No. The reconstructed Classical pronunciation is for Latin; it doesn't make sense to talk about that specific pronunciation for any language that's not Latin. The changes that happened over the past few millennia are what make French French, and Spanish Spanish, and so on; you can't ignore those changes and still have the result be recognizably French/Spanish/etc.

Comment: However I think that reconstructed Classical Latin pronunciation can be used for Latin phrases (like *et cētera*, *exemplī grātiā*, *curriculum vītae*) used inside sentences in some other language (English, French, Spanish etc.).